# Click on IAccessible(MSAA) element without DefaultAction

Tags: python, ui-automation, msaa, iaccessible

I've been trying to create an automated test with MSAA on python using [pyMSAA](https://github.com/phus/pyMSAA)

I faced with a problem when a button does not have DefaultAction

```
b.accDoDefaultAction()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "msaa.py", line 215, in accDoDefaultAction
    self.IAccessible._IAccessible__com_accDoDefaultAction(objChildId)
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', (None, None, None, 0, None)
)
```

I found out that the absence of DefaultAction is normal.

Is there any way to make a click(double-click) on such elements? Send some event, etc...
I am thinking about clicking by coordinates, but it may be not a good idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sending a mouse click is definitely possible (using SendInput or the Python equivalent).  The thing you have do first is verify that your clickable point is actually going to the object you want to click (i.e., the clickable point might be obscured by another window/control).

You can use [AccessibleObjectFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (this seems to be wrapped by `msaa.point` in pyMSAA) to check that the accessible object under the point is in fact the same object you're trying to click.

Now you can check various points in the `accLocation` to find your clickable point.  The best initial point is the center; if that fails, try points at 1/3, 1/2, 2/3s of the width (or height, as appropriate) in both the x and y directions.